# Selenium RC 2.24.1 + Firefox 10.0.2 Profiles

Tags: firefox, selenium

After many tests with many old versions of Firefox (3.0.19, 3.6.28, 10.0.2) I have some trouble.

My last test was to launch "selenium-server-standalone-2.24.1.jar" with this args : -firefoxProfileTemplate C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\g3c1ac71.Profile_FF_10

In this profile I have configured language to French but it doesn't work, my website is display in English. I also had an SSL exception but when selenium launch my site, Firefox give me an alert about selfsigned certificate

With version 3.0.19, profile was used but Firefox crashed because of Flash plugin, so I know I know use profile.

It's really hard to understand compatibilty between selenium and Firefox.

Is this a special step I forgot ?

Regard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I reboot my computer, all work like a charm. Strange !